# Get User's Email from Azure Active Directory using a WebApp developed in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, web-applications, directory

I have a web app developed in ASP.NET MVC CORE.  It is hosted on Azure and I currently use Azure active directory for users to access it.  Is there a way to obtain their email or name and store it within the web app?

Comment: Within Web app means app database? If so yes you can.  You can fetch all the user list using Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to get the user's name and save it into table storage so i know who uploaded what data to the website

Comment: You can use Microsoft Graph API to fetch user information from your azure active directory tenant. Just need to call that API from your web application and finally save it where you wanted to.